# xmlexists with namespace in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltable, oracle-xml-db

I am having issues figuring out how to integrate namespaces to a where clause having xmlexists. The query is as below:

```
SELECT sing_d1.sing_info_text1, sing_d1.sing_info_text2
FROM XMLTABLE(
      xmlnamespaces (
                       'http://www.abccompany.com/Canonical' AS "abc",
                       'http://abccompany.com/PmtInfo' AS "pmt",
                       'http://abccompany.com/CommonTypes' AS "cmn",
                       'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi"),
                   '/abc:abc/abc:Pmt/pmt:Payments/pmt:PayInfo/pmt:Single/pmt:SingAddInfo'
                    PASSING payXml
                    COLUMNS 
                                  sing_info_type VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpType',
                                  sing_info_text1 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[1]',
                                  sing_info_text2 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[2]'
              )sing_d1
WHERE 
                       XMLExists(

                   '/abc:abc/abc:Pmt/pmt:Payments/pmt:PayInfo/pmt:Single/pmt:SingAddInfo[AddInfoCmpType = "IATCode"]'

);
```

Any clues would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to write `WHERE sing_info_type = 'IATCode'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
   XMLExists('   declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
                declare namespace abc="http://www.abccompany.com/Canonical";
                        declare namespace pmt="http://abccompany.com/PmtInfo";
                        declare namespace cmn="http://abccompany.com/CommonTypes";
                          /abc:abc/abc:Pmt/pmt:Payments/pmt:PayInfo/pmt:Single/pmt:SingAddInfo[AddInfoCmpType = "IATCode"]' passing payXml)
```

For xmlns(default) use `declare default element namespace "http.url.url"`. For other  `declare namespace xyz`

Comment: Thanks AL. But now the code which is in a procedure is failing with FAIL:Others errorORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix '.' local-name ''.

Comment: I do not know what i was thinking. I need to actually use the xmlexists functionality before the select, cause a where clause with the xmlexists will still make the select fail with no_data_found if the tag is missing from an xml. Can xmlexists be used with an IF clause to check if the data exists before going into the select?

Comment: `select case when XMLExists('/a/b' passing  xmltype('<a><b></b></a>')) then 'YES' else 'NO' end  into var from dual;
 /`

 `select EXISTSNODE(xmltype('<a><b></b></a>'), '/a/b') into var from dual\
 /`

In `EXISTSNODE` namespaces go as last paramter `,'xmlns:abc="url.abc" xmlns:xyz="url.xyz"'`